# При появлении клавиатуры поднимается layout с listview

Tags: android, listview

При появлении клавиатуры поднимается layout с listview...

Как отменить поднятие lauout-a ?

Вот xml

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="#75F575">

<LinearLayout
android:clickable="true"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="250dp"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:background="#C69817"
android:id="@+id/secondLayout">

<Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:id="@+id/mainButton1"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mainListView1"/>

 </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Клава вызывается напр. так:

```
InputMethodManager imm=(InputMethodManager)getSystemService (Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        if (imm != null)
                        {
                            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
                        }
```

Вот весь код:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainListView1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> a = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,  new String [] {"item1","item2"});
    lv.setAdapter(a);
}

public void onClick(View v){
    InputMethodManager imm=(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (imm != null)
    {
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
    } 
    }
```

Но чертовый listview все равно двигается вгору , ему все равно что нет никаких эдитбоксов и так далее...

Это не помогает полностью : android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
Листвью все равно частично двигается, да и костылевое это решение. Почему то layout считает, что если появляется клавиатура, то нужно обязательно двигать лисвью. Вот как бы это отменить в самом листвью, может быть ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Наконец то нашел решение - нужно добавить в listview такие атрибуты:

> android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
>           android:isScrollContainer="false"